# Django passing multiple variables in render

Tags: python, django

I am trying to pass multiple variables in Django render. One of them is the csrf token and the other one is my form (because I need the errors from the form) For some reason none of them work. Any help?

Here is the template :

```
<form class = "navbar-form" action="{% url "registry.views.register" %}" onsubmit=" return ClickButton();  " method= "POST" >
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.errors}} {{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

here is the view.py:

def register(request):

```
form_save = RegisterationForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegisterationForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        user_info={}
        user_info['username'] = form.cleaned_data['username']
        user_info['password'] = form.cleaned_data['password']


        form.save(user_info)
        return render_to_response('register_success.html',user_info)

    else:
        form_save = form


return render_to_response('register.html',{'csrf':csrf(request),'locals':locals()})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why pass `csrf` manually? `{% csrf_token %}` does that automatically.

Also, if you are using any newer version of Django, you can use `render()`.

```
return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you were not using the **{}** litteral dictionary, I'd suggest changing:

```
return render_to_response('register.html',{'csrf':csrf(request),'locals':locals()})
```

to use the ** to expand the locals()-returned dictionary into keywords.  But that will probably not work.

```
return render_to_response('register.html',{'csrf':csrf(request),**locals()})
```

Try this instead:

```
my_dict = {csrf:csrf(request)}

my_dict.update(locals())

return render_to_response(
    'register.html',
    my_dict,

)
```

That said, probably cleaner to explicitly pass what you want, using the **dict** constructor:

```
return render_to_response(
    'register.html',
    dict(
        csrf=csrf(request),
        user_info=user_info,
        form=form,
    )

)
```

And the reason your template doesn't find say **form** is that it isn't there at in the context.  The context has **csrf** and **locals**, where **form** resides.  You could reference **{{locals.form}}** instead.  But that's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass your `csrf` token, you can decorate your `view` function with `@csrf_protect` to pass the token to the current context. The form can be added to the context dictionary:

```
@csrf_protect
def your_view(request):
    # process request

    # add form to context dictionary, and return RequestContext for current request
    return render_to_response('register.html', {'form': form}, RequestContext(request))
```

Alternatively, you can do a site wide `csrf` protection by adding `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` (usually added by default). You should read more from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/)